# Overwriting a file programmatically in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa

This code copies the referenced file and places it in the Docs Directory. I'm trying to build a simple backup solution. The problem is this operation does not overwrite the existing file if the operation is repeated.

Two questions:

What's the best way to overwrite in code?

How difficult would it be to append the current date to each copied file? In this case there would be no overwrite operation. This would be much more useful for keeping incremental backups. If I decide to do it this way I understand I would need to create a new path in order to keep things organized.

Thanks.

Paul

```
    NSString * name  = @"testFile";
NSArray  * files = [NSArray arrayWithObject: name];

NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];

[ws performFileOperation: NSWorkspaceCopyOperation
                  source: @"~/Library/Application Support/testApp"
             destination: @"~/Documents/"
                   files: files
                     tag: 0];
```

Comment: On each path containing a tilde you should call `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` like this: `[@"~/Documents/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]`.

Comment: @Paul did it do the job?

Comment: better yet in broader usage `- [NSString stringByStandardizingPath]`

Comment: @Radek Not yet. I'll be on it in a a few hours. I appreciate the tips from you and Justin as well.

Comment: @Radek, not working for me. Still not overwriting. stringByStandardizingPath didn't work either. I added both to the destination:@"" line. Am I off track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using NSFileManager, example below (untested):

```
// Better way to get the Application Support Directory, similar method for Documents Directory
- (NSString *)applicationSupportDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : NSTemporaryDirectory();
    return [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testApp"];
}  

- (void) removeFile {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [self applicationSupportDirectory];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSString* filePath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"testFile"];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath isDirectory:NULL]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
}
```

Edit: 
Take a look at the [NSFileManager Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for other functions that might be useful (for your second question).

Comment: I get a "Passing argument 2 'removeItemAtPath:error.' from incompatible pointer type" warning

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. The function definition is `- (BOOL)removeItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` which requires an `NSError**`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent. Got this working. I set things up so that the backup file is stored in ~/Documents/Backup. The code above deletes the existing file and opens up the directory for the new file copied and moved into the same directory. Thanks again.